# how to store two string in a line to different variables batch

Tags: batch-file

I have file which has data below in single line:-

```
Folder\Folder1\Folde2\file1.txt             Folder\Folder1\Folde2\file.txt
```

I need to get each of them in a variable, can anyone please provides any leads.

I tried awk but not able to do so.

Comment: Do you need them in shell variables or awk variables?

Comment: I am writing a batch script, so storing it in awk.

Comment: `awk '{first=$1;second=$2}' file` assuming there is no space in neither of the paths.

Comment: There is space between both the paths in the file

Comment: _between_ the paths or _in_ the paths? If _in_ you're in a bad place.

Comment: its between the path :),  I need to iterate the file as each line has data

Comment: In that case just use the above. For each line in file `file` awk sets the first space-separated string (`$1`)  into variable `first` and the second string (`$2`) into `second`.

Comment: is this windows `batch-file` as tagged?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your `batch-file` tag and the fact that you use `\` in your paths, makes me assume this is Windows Batch file. If it is the case, then see below, if not the case I will delete or update my answer, but then please also update your tags and question accordingly.

This is if you really want to set it as a variable:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%i in (file.txt) do (
   set "var1=%%i"
   set "var2=%%j"
   echo !var1!
   echo !var2!
)
```

You could obviously skip the variable option, because you can use the pre-defined vars and also eliminate the use of `delayedexpansion` :

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=1,2" %%i in (file.txt) do (
   echo %%i
   echo %%j
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to get the them into bash variables, so my anwser is like this:

```
first=`awk '{print $1}' file`
echo $first
second=`awk '{print $2}' file`
echo $second
```

Comment: it is Windows batch file, incorrectly tagged with `awk` by user.